# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL database within pgAdminIII

Tags: postgresql, connectivity

I have two databases within one Postgres server, and I am unable to connect to one of these databases. Upon a connection attempt, pgAdmin gets hung on "retrieving details on database." I'm able to connect to all other databases successfully.

Comment: Can you connect using `psql`?  Is it possible there are so many database objects that pgAdmin cannot handle them?